# AutoCAD Architecture Vision Tools in AutoCAD

Tags: autocad

I have both AutoCAD and AutoCAD Architecture installed on my system. AutoCAD Architecture has a tab called Vision Tools with a nifty command called Display By Layer to set the display order of objects in accordance with the layers of the drawing. Is there anyway to add this tab or use this command in AutoCAD?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're looking for a built-in feature or APIs for it.

For a built in feature, check the [DRAWORDER command](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-3DC76D6E-8F81-4803-8D0A-AA7541D6357E-htm.html). For an API/programming approach, check the respective [DrawOrderTable](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/changing-draworder-of-entities.html) method. See below:

**Update**: please also check this 3rd party tool: [DoByLayer](http://www.dotsoft.com/freestuff.htm).

```
[CommandMethod("SendToBottom")]
public void commandDrawOrderChange()
{
    Document activeDoc
                = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
    Database db = activeDoc.Database;
    Editor ed = activeDoc.Editor;

    PromptEntityOptions peo
                = new PromptEntityOptions("Select an entity : ");
    PromptEntityResult per = ed.GetEntity(peo);
    if (per.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
    {
        return;
    }
    ObjectId oid = per.ObjectId;

    SortedList<long, ObjectId> drawOrder
                            = new SortedList<long, ObjectId>();

    using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    {
        BlockTable bt = tr.GetObject(   
                                        db.BlockTableId,
                                        OpenMode.ForRead
                                    ) as BlockTable;
        BlockTableRecord btrModelSpace =
                tr.GetObject(
                                bt[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace],
                                OpenMode.ForRead
                            ) as BlockTableRecord;

        DrawOrderTable dot =
                tr.GetObject(
                                btrModelSpace.DrawOrderTableId,
                                OpenMode.ForWrite
                            ) as DrawOrderTable;

        ObjectIdCollection objToMove = new ObjectIdCollection();
        objToMove.Add(oid);
        dot.MoveToBottom(objToMove);

        tr.Commit();
    }
    ed.WriteMessage("Done");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Augusto, but yes, it is a built in feature. When I open up AutoCAD Architecture and set my profile to AutoCAD Architecture (US Metric) and I type the command _AECLAYERORDER it opens up the Display Order by Layer feature. When I switch to the AutoCAD profile, there's no such command. So I am thinking there must be a way to add it to AutoCAD.

Comment: Thanks again for your input in this matter Augusto. I do have the DoByLayer tool installed, but the thing with it is that the layer order isn't updated on the fly. Each time you draw a new line or object you need to run the command, adjust the order of the layers and only then is the draw order of the new lines updated to the order of the layers. With AutoCAD Architecture's Display By Layer feature, whenever you draw a new line or object, it's draw order is immediately adjusted according to the order of the layers.

Comment: understood, but if you want to really automate something, you probably need to customize via API/programming

Answer (score 0):

With some help from VBA it might look by this. Note i did not add fancy listbox code. I just show the worker and how to list layers. The trivial Code to add things to a listbox on a form and how to sort / rearrange listbox items can be found on any excel / VBA forum on the web . Or you just uses a predefined string like in the example. To get VBA to work download and install the acc. VBA Enabler from autocad. It is free.

```
           'select all items on a layer by a filter    
             Sub selectALayer(sset As AcadSelectionSet, layername As String)

               Dim filterType As Variant
               Dim filterData As Variant
               Dim p1(0 To 2) As Double
               Dim p2(0 To 2) As Double

               Dim grpCode(0) As Integer
               grpCode(0) = 8
               filterType = grpCode
               Dim grpValue(0) As Variant
               grpValue(0) = layername
               filterData = grpValue
               sset.Select acSelectionSetAll, p1, p2, filterType, filterData
               Debug.Print "layer", layername, "Entities: " & str(sset.COUNT)

            End Sub

            'bring items on top
            Sub OrderToTop(layername As String)
                ' This example creates a SortentsTable object and
                ' changes the draw order of selected object(s) to top.
                Dim oSset As AcadSelectionSet
                Dim oEnt
                Dim i As Integer
                Dim setName As String

                setName = "$Order$"
                'Make sure selection set does not exist

                For i = 0 To ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.COUNT - 1
                    If ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.ITEM(i).NAME = setName Then
                        ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.ITEM(i).DELETE
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next i

                setName = "tmp_" & time()
                Set oSset = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add(setName)
                Call selectALayer(oSset, layername)

                If oSset.COUNT > 0 Then
                    ReDim arrObj(0 To oSset.COUNT - 1) As ACADOBJECT
                    'Process each object
                    i = 0
                    For Each oEnt In oSset
                        Set arrObj(i) = oEnt
                        i = i + 1
                    Next
                End If

                'kills also left over selectionset by programming mistakes....
                For Each selectionset In ThisDrawing.SelectionSets
                    selectionset.delete_by_layer_space
                Next


                On Error GoTo Err_Control
                'Get an extension dictionary and, if necessary, add a SortentsTable object
                Dim eDictionary As Object
                Set eDictionary = ThisDrawing.modelspace.GetExtensionDictionary

                ' Prevent failed GetObject calls from throwing an exception
                On Error Resume Next
                Dim sentityObj As Object
                Set sentityObj = eDictionary.GetObject("ACAD_SORTENTS")

                On Error GoTo 0

                If sentityObj Is Nothing Then
                    ' No SortentsTable object, so add one
 Set sentityObj = eDictionary.AddObject("ACAD_SORTENTS", "AcDbSortentsTable")
                End If

                'Move selected object(s) to the top
                sentityObj.MoveToTop arrObj
                applicaTION.UPDATE

                Exit Sub
                  Err_Control:
                If ERR.NUMBER > 0 Then MsgBox ERR.DESCRIPTION
            End Sub


            Sub bringtofrontbylist()
                Dim lnames As String
                'predefined layer names 
                layer_names = "foundation bridge road"
                Dim h() As String
                h = split(layernames)
                For i = 0 To UBound(h)
                    Call OrderToTop(h(i))
                Next
            End Sub


            'in case you want a fancy form here is how to get list / all layers                
            Sub list_layers()
            Dim LAYER As AcadLayer
            For Each LAYER In ThisDrawing.LAYERS
                Debug.Print LAYER.NAME

            Next
            End Sub
```

to make it run put the cursor inside the VBA IDE inside the code of list_layers andpress F5 or choose it from the VBA Macro list.